# 请教一下『还』字（huan2、hai2 两者）的语源

Tags: meaning, difference, old-chinese

『还』字的这两个读音，韵母不一样，实际意思差别也挺大的。

当它读作`huan2`是指『回归』之意，可以译作『return』，是个动词；

但是若以`hai2`音来翻译，应当是代表了一种『当下并没有，但以后可能会这样』的状态，译作『still/yet』等副词。

我私下里就想，这俩意思之间有着千差万别，从上古汉语追溯下来，应该不是同源的吧？

然后我就去网上搜了一圈，在《说文》和《康熙字典》里也没找到什么特别的注解。

我这作为一个北京人，在汉语上遇到了问题，还要来国际网站上发帖，真是惭愧。不过子曾经曰过：『敏而好学，不耻下问』，这不懂的就要问。

还是麻烦您帮着解答一下我的疑惑了，谢谢！

Btw be free to answer/discuss in English, I was just thinking that this website is just all about Chinese, so I posted this question in Chinese. :-D

Answer (score 2):

「還」（`huan2`），从「辵」（辶），「睘」（瞏）聲。「回歸」、「復也」是「還」字的本意，古文也偶爾用「睘」字假借爲「復也」之意。現代普通話 `hai2`、 `huan2` 二者有分工作用，前者是表示副詞的讀法，但古文竝不出現這種用法，`huan2`、`hai2` 的上古、中古等先音混用在「復也」、副詞之意。`Hai2` 先音不現於反切記錄，可能是白讀。

---

「睘」部在「還」裏衹是聲符，「睘」从「目」，「袁」省聲，本意是「目驚視也」，跟「復也」的意思不同。「睘」字在古文多被爲「還」、「環」、「縣」、「煢」詞的假借字。

「還」也當過假借字。例：

- 「環」

  - 散氏盤：「道以東一奉（封），還（環），以西一奉（封）。」
  - 《馬王堆．五十二病方》第101行：「取井中泥，以還（環）封其傷。」
- 「懷」

  - 《郭店簡．尊德義》簡25：「治民非還（懷）生而已也。」

Axel Schussler 認爲「還，復也」本从南亞語系，跟高棉語 *raṅvā’na* `repayment; return; recompense` 同源。「還」副詞意的詞源不明，可能在荀子之前就出現這種用法：

> 《荀子．王霸》：「如是則禹舜還至，王業還起。」

當副詞，現在衹能釋「還」爲假借，有新證據之後文學家再可復考。